# Why is my Java code not working (beginner, array)

Tags: java, arrays

thanks for looking. I'm stuck on why this is not handling cases for inputted grades. It handles A+ fine (returns 4.0) but 'A' gives an error, 'A-' gives 4.0 (should be 3.7), then 'B+' is correct, 'B' gives error, 'B-' gives 3.0 (should be 2.7), and this is the pattern. Any thoughts?

````
public class Grade {
    private String grade = "";
    public Grade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    public double getgrade() {
        double gpa = 0.0;
        char[] gradeArray = this.grade.toCharArray();
        if (gradeArray[0] == 'A') {
            gpa += 4.0;
        }
        if (gradeArray[0] == 'B') {
            gpa += 3.0;
        }
        if (gradeArray[0] == 'C') {
            gpa += 2.0;
        }
        if (gradeArray[0] == 'D') {
            gpa += 1.0;
        }        
        if (gradeArray[1] == '+') {
            if (gradeArray[0] != 'A') {
                gpa += 0.3;
            }
        }
        if (gradeArray[0] == '-') {
            gpa -= 0.3;
        }
        return gpa;
    }
}```
````

Comment: `if (gradeArray[0] == '-') {` explains the other issue.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, or correct it if it is exactly the same as you posted. Your methods don't end properly in the code you posted, as they lack the closing curly braces.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will do this

Comment: What if they pass something other than `A-D`, `+` or `-`?  I'd do some validation in the constructor and throw an exception if necessary...

Answer (score 1):

well if you call A or B, e.g.:

```
new Grade("A").getNumericGrade()
```

you get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException on line

```
if (gradeArray[1] == '+') {
```

because gradeArray[1] does not exist, there is only 1 character (at index 0) it is 'A' or 'B'

Simple solution: check for length! E.g.:

```
if (gradeArray.length > 1 && gradeArray[1] == '+') {
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Grade {

```
private String grade = "";

public Grade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getLetterGrade() {
    return this.grade;
}

public double getNumericGrade() {
    double gpa = 0.0;
    char[] gradeArray = this.grade.toCharArray();

    // Good to have null/empty check always
    if ( gradeArray.length == 0  || gradeArray[0] == ' '){
        return 0;
    }

    // Code readability increases manifolds with switch. if clause can also be used
    // Considering only the cases you originally had. With this your code block at last becomes redundant
    switch ( gradeArray[0] ){
        case 'A': gpa += 4.0; break;
        case 'B': gpa += 3.0; break;
        case 'C': gpa += 2.0; break;
        case 'D': gpa += 1.0; break;
        default: break;
    }

    // First you need to check if there is a second character present or not
    // If present then it should be only +/-
    if( gradeArray.length == 2 && ( gradeArray[1] == '+' || gradeArray[1] == '-' )){
        if (gradeArray[1] == '+') {
            if (gradeArray[0] != 'A') {
                gpa += 0.3;
            }
        }
        // '-' would be second character, so index should be 1
        if (gradeArray[1] == '-') {
            gpa -= 0.3;
        }
    } //Include else to handle other scenarios

    return gpa;
}
```

}

Comment: Logic is mentioned in comments. Fixed a few typos!